# Discretization size and Recurrence period of numpy uniform

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random, precision

My queries are regarding the generation of the uniform random number generator using `numpy.random.uniform` on `[0,1)`.

1. Does this implementation involve a uniform `step-size`, i.e. are the universe of possibilities `{0,a,2a,...,Na}` where `(N+1)a = 1` and `a` is constant?
2. If the above is true, then what's the value of this `step-size`? I noticed that the value of `numpy.nextafter(x,y)` keeps on changing depending upon `x`. Hence my question regarding whether a uniform `step-size` was used to implement `numpy.random.uniform`.
3. If the `step-size` is not uniform, then what would be the best way to figure out the number of unique values that `numpy.random.uniform(low=0, high=1)` can take?
4. What's the recurrence period of `numpy.random.uniform`, i.e. after how many samples will I see my original number again? For maximum efficiency, this should be equal to the number of unique values.

I tried looking up the source code at [Github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx) but didn't find anything directly interpretable there.

Comment: What exactly you're asking in #4? Single number repetition? This would be at best something like 2^32 - 2^25 for floats, or 2^64-2^52 for doubles. Sequence repetition? Something like 2^19337-1

Comment: Sequence repetition. It should be 2^19337-1 for a Mersenne Twister.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant function is

```
double
rk_double(rk_state *state)
{
    /* shifts : 67108864 = 0x4000000, 9007199254740992 = 0x20000000000000 */
    long a = rk_random(state) >> 5, b = rk_random(state) >> 6;
    return (a * 67108864.0 + b) / 9007199254740992.0;
}
```

which is found in randomkit.c inside the numpy source tree.
As you can see the granularity is `1 / 9007199254740992.0` which happens to equal 2^-53 which is the (downward) float64 resolution at 1.

```
>>> 1 / 9007199254740992.0
1.1102230246251565e-16
>>> 2**-53
1.1102230246251565e-16
>>> 1-np.nextafter(1.0, 0)
1.1102230246251565e-16
```

Comment: Thanks! Any clue about the recurrence period or how I can find it?

Comment: @AmritPrasad I think it's a Mersenne twister defined in `mtrand.c`. But I do not know its period.